# export: * not a valid identifier, whenever I use bash?

Tags: bash

I keep seeing

```
 -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
 -bash: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java': not a valid identifier
 -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
 -bash: export: `/usr/share/tomcat7': not a valid identifier
```

I know its when I was installing tomcat7 and java stuff but I can't remember where I made these changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "not a valid identifier" error after setting environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/q/529919/22949) The answers there give details about what kinds of syntax mistakes produce "not a valid identifier" errors and specifically how to fix them. In particular, [mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/532873/22949) gives details about "not a valid identifier" errors showing `/`-delimited paths and also about such errors showing `=`, and [Patrick Mutuku's](https://askubuntu.com/a/935606/22949) gives brief, good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its saying that you have some problems in your .bashrc.

type as `nano ~/.bashrc` in your terminal.

check at that area of the lines and fix those errors.

then save & close.

then again type as bash or  open your terminal .

Comment: it says cannot open display

Comment: creates a new blank file when I do user@ubuntu:/$ sudo nano .bashrc

Comment: but it gives "permission denied" error
{user@ubuntu:/$ nano .bashrc

Error reading /home/riaa/.nano_history: Permission denied

Press Enter to continue starting nano.} then creates new file again

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04
Codename:       raring

Comment: you were right on what I needed to do. But the terminal command is  nano ~/.bashrc which worked for me.